# Google Drive REST API - Are custom properties indexed?

Tags: google-drive-api

As stated in the google drive api doc that we can add metadata to files using custom properties. My question is if these custom properties are internally indexed by google?

My worry is that if any functionality depends on the custom properties then do we have to worry about the number of files in the drive? E.g. if the total number of files in drive increases to 10 million in future state, will querying on custom property not work or will work too slow to be useful?

Answer (score 0):

[Custom file properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties) are:

> Properties that are **stored as key/value pairs** on the Drive file.
>   Properties may be **visible** to all apps, or **restricted** to the app that
>   creates the property.
>
> Properties are accessed using the `properties` (visible to all apps) and
>   `appProperties` (restricted to single apps) fields on [files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files).

Using properties will allow your app to store additional metadata on a file, such as tags, IDs from other data stores, viewing preferences etc. Properties can be used to share metadata between applications, for example, in a workflow application.

> Writing a file property has the same performance implications as other
>   write operations.

It means these properties has an effect that depends on the usage limits from any application.

Here are the [list of usage limits of Custom properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties).

Comment: Hey Jess! Thanks for replying. I saw this content on google documents already however it does not answer if the properties are indexed. I am asking this to know the scalability of apps built which are using these properties.